# Fetching JSONP with React Native

Tags: react-native, jsonp, fetch

I'm trying to use this API https://www.petfinder.com/developers/api-docs with React Native. The problem I'm having is it returns JSONP rather than JSON so using fetch is giving me an unexpected token in JSON error. I've tried to use a library like fetch-jsonP, however thats not working in React Native because there is no document (same with jquery), any ideas how I can get jsonP data with React Native?

App.js

```
class Home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      `http://api.petfinder.com/pet.find?format=json&key=${API_KEY}&animal=dog&location=84070&callback=callback`
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responseText => console.log(responseText))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

    return (
      <View>
        <Header
          backgroundColor={darkBlue}
          leftComponent={{ icon: "menu", color: "#fff" }}
          centerComponent={<HeaderTextComponent />}
          rightComponent={{ icon: "home", color: "#fff" }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Have you tried [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146650/get-json-from-jsonp-fetch-promise)?

Comment: Yes I have, when running that code with my fetch call i get 'invalid JSONP response', so the error I'm throwing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONP works only in browsers, not on mobile. Don't try to use fetch-jsonP or any JSONP library because they rely on document.createElement('script') to get Cross-Domain Support. On mobiles, Cross-Domain makes no sense.

As I see on petfinder.com the JSONP is used only if you supply a callback. If you won't do so I expect to get a normal JSON response.

Comment: Yeah that ended up being the solution